# Count number of words in each sentence Spark Dataframes

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark Dataframe where each row has a review.

```
+--------------------+
|          reviewText| 
+--------------------+
|Spiritually and m...|
|This is one my mu...|
|This book provide...|
|I first read THE ...|
+--------------------+
```

I have tried:

```
SplitSentences = df.withColumn("split_sent",sentencesplit_udf(col('reviewText')))
SplitSentences = SplitSentences.select(SplitSentences.split_sent)
```

Then I created the function:

```
def word_count(text):
    return len(text.split())

wordcount_udf = udf(lambda x: word_count(x))

df2 = SplitSentences.withColumn("word_count", 
  wordcount_udf(col('split_sent')).cast(IntegerType())
```

I want to count the words of each sentence in each review (row) but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `split` *inbuilt function* to split the sentences and use the `size` *inbuilt function* to count the length of the array as

```
df.withColumn("word_count", F.size(F.split(df['reviewText'], ' '))).show(truncate=False)
```

This way you won't need the *expensive udf function*

As an example, lets say you have following *one sentence dataframe*

```
+-----------------------------+
|reviewText                   |
+-----------------------------+
|this is text testing spliting|
+-----------------------------+
```

After applying above `size` and `split` function you should be getting

```
+-----------------------------+----------+
|reviewText                   |word_count|
+-----------------------------+----------+
|this is text testing spliting|5         |
+-----------------------------+----------+
```

**If you have multiple sentences in one row** as below

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|reviewText                                                                        |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|this is text testing spliting. this is second sentence. And this is the third one.|
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Then you will have to write a `udf` function as below

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
def countWordsInEachSentences(array):
    return [len(x.split()) for x in array]

countWordsSentences = F.udf(lambda x: countWordsInEachSentences(x.split('. ')))

df.withColumn("word_count", countWordsSentences(df['reviewText'])).show(truncate=False)
```

which should give you

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
|reviewText                                                                        |word_count|
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
|this is text testing spliting. this is second sentence. And this is the third one.|[5, 4, 6] |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
```

I hope the answer is helpful