# How replace multiple commas by single comma and count words in each line of a Pyspark DataFrame?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a huge data set, in each row there are some titles that have been separated by `,`. I want to do two things:

1- remove `,` if they are followed by each other.

2- count words between `,`.

For example, consider the following two rows:

```
      column
hello, I am wondering/low,,, Going/hi, towards,, Host
winter, summer,,
```

expected output:

```
      column                                        count
hello, I am wondering/low, Going/hi, towards, Host    5
winter, summer,                                       2
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count number of words in each sentence Spark Dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49267331/count-number-of-words-in-each-sentence-spark-dataframes)

Comment: yes, and what I should do if I have `,,` I want separate words by `,` and not space. then when I have `,,` it makes problem

Comment: use `,` to split instead of space and replace multiple commas with single

Comment: I am not sure how many of them do I have. so using replace is not gonna work

Comment: @mck is there any code that say if there is more than one `,` followed by each other remove and keep one?

Comment: @mck this code changes `,,` to `,` . can I also add `,,,' , `,,,,` and more in this code? or I should write a different code for each? `df.withColumn('Title_lower_case', regexp_replace('Title_lower_case', ',,', ','))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1- remove `,` if they are followed by each other.

Use regex to replace more than one comma by a single one using [`regexp_replace`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#regexp_replace) function. You can use the regex `,{2,}` which means 2 or more commas.

> 2- count words between `,`.

As pointed in the linked other question, you need to simply split the values and get the size of the array. But here you can have commas at the end of the values, so `size` will be greater than actual words. For this, you have to [`filter`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#filter) the array first to eliminate empty strings.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace, expr

data = [
    ("hello, I am wondering / low,,, Going / hi, towards,, Host",),
    ("winter, summer,,",)
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["column"])

df1 = df.withColumn("column", regexp_replace("column", ",{2,}", ",")) \
    .withColumn("count",
                expr("size(filter(split(column, ','), x -> nullif(x, '') is not null))")
                )

df1.show(truncate=False)

#+------------------------------------------------------+-----+
#|column                                                |count|
#+------------------------------------------------------+-----+
#|hello, I am wondering / low, Going / hi, towards, Host|5    |
#|winter, summer,                                       |2    |
#+------------------------------------------------------+-----+
```

Comment: why it just give me the count column?